# Vim Error E138: Can't write viminfo file $HOME/.viminfo!

Tags: permissions, vim, sudo, root

I'm afraid I've run into something rather strange. When I open a file normally, `vim README.txt`, everything is fine. But upon `sudo vim README.txt`, the file renders blank, and gives me a `E138: Can't write viminfo file $HOME/.viminfo!` error upon trying to exit.

I suspected the `.viminfo` file was corrupt, so I deleted it. This problem remains. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post result when running `ls .viminf*`?

Comment: What are the permissions on the viminfo file? What is the output of `ls -la .vininf*`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you run `sudo vim` you start vim as root. That means that it is the viminfo file in /root that is the problem. You should do `rm /root/.viminf*`.

To make sure of this, run `sudo vim` and execute this command: `:!echo $HOME`.
This will show you that your home directory is /root.

I would recommend that you do not run vim as root, but rather use `sudoedit`. This is a more secure solution as the editor is not running as root. You never know what a plugin might do. Additionally it allows you to use your own settings and plugins in vim and not the ones in roots vimrc. `sudoedit` is the same as running `sudo -e`. sudoedit works by making a temporary copy of the file that is owned by the invoking user (you). When you finish editing, the changes are written to the actual file and the temporary file is deleted.

As a general rule of thumb: Do not run things as root if it is not necessary.

Comment: I think you might have saved me from a bunch of worry with the note, "This is a more secure solution as the editor is not running as root. **You never know what a plugin might do.**" I believed that I had thought of all vulnerabilities, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 30):

I got this error on every exit. I did not use `sudo`. It explicitly mentioned my user home directory:

```
E138: Can't write viminfo file /Users/henrik/.viminfo!
```

Removing `~/.viminfo` did not fix the error.

Turns out I had a bunch of viminfo temp files, and removing those fixed the issue:

```
 ls ~/.viminf*      # If you want to see the files.
 rm -rf ~/.viminf*  # Remove them.
```

Found this solution [here](http://tekabhi.blogspot.com/2007/08/solution-e138-in-vi-editor.html).

Comment: I'd suggest using `rm  ~/.viminf*.tmp` - no forcing and no subdirs, to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 11):

I received the same error when trying to `:wq` a file on a disk that was completely full. If you receive this message, you may wish to check your available disk space.

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was that I had changed my home directory to location inside an NFS mount. For some reason, this resulted in the owner of the directory to be "nobody". Adding write permissions for "other" solved the problem as I was clearly not the owner of the file.

```
chmod o+w ~/.viminfo
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer. Oneline answers do not count as good in SE

Comment: Odd that adding *other* write permissions helped you. Perhaps you didn't own your own file?

Comment: This works for me. I guess my ".viminfo" was created by user "root" and if user "ubuntu" tries to modify it, he needs a write permission. In a nutshell, "-rw-r--r--" becomes "-rw-r--rw-".

Answer (score 2):

A much more cleaner way to create a home directory would be to use the skeleton that linux provides for you for example.

```
sudo cp -a /etc/skel /home/usernmae && sudo chown -R usernmae:usernmae /home/usernmae
```

Comment: I'm afraid the question has very little to do with the creation of home directories...

Comment: You need to create a home directory in order for vim to be able to save to the .viminfo file, so yes the above command is applicable.

Comment: There are countless reasons why this file wouldn't exist, before you can reach such a conclusion. The absence of a home directory would probably cause much more trouble than just a missing file ; with this reason I could answer pretty any "missing file" question with "create your home directory". :)

Comment: +1 In my case, this error occurred exactly because I was editing a file as a user which didn't have a home directory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have cleared environment variables.

Do this:

export HOME=/root

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is happening because the home dir has run out of disk space and any new vim operation is unable to write in the .viminfo file.

Comment: That seems a bit farfetched: do you have any evidence for that?

Comment: That is one possibility, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when updating the content of Makefile. I needed a local variable and decided to  name it `HOME`, so I entered the line `HOME=2.154`. This causes the `vim-HOME` setting to be replaced by a non-existing directory. Don't use the `HOME` variable for other use.

Comment: Please note that `HOME` is a predefined environment variable and re-defining it is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may only apply to pretty old versions of linux/vi but what I found was that there were temporary files in the root's home directory with the filenames /root/.viminfa.tmp ... /root/.viminfz.tmp and that there were 26 of them with timestamps covering several years. We had run out of letters of the alphabet as all of a-z were taken.  I removed all of those files and the problem dissappeared.
Of course Henrik's
`# rm -rf ~/.viminf*`
would fix this problem just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I came across this scenario myself as I don't recall opening any files using `sudo vim` but on each `:q` of a file I was getting a similar 'Can't write viminfo is not writeable'.

`rm ~/.viminfo` didn't resolve it and `~/.vim/` was empty.

`chmod 666 ~/.viminfo` resolved that warning message when exiting a file in Vim. Although I'm not certain this is the best solution? It makes sense why it stopped the warning since .viminfo was rw------ before and I assume is getting written to with vim command histories.

Answer (score 0):

I my scenario, it was the absence of `/root/.viminfo` file altogether. After I touched the file, the error stopped and the file was updated up on exiting vim. 
PS : This is windriver embedded linux.